# $d=2$ pole argument of quadratic divergences in Peskin & Schroeder's book

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, regularization, fine-tuning, dimensional-regularization

**Q1:**
My question is, in the context of dimensional regularisation(DREG, in dimension $d$), why do they mention the absence of $d=2$ pole in the gauge theory cases[1], whereas the $d=2$ pole is not discussed about in $\lambda\phi^4$ theory[2]?

For details, refer to Peskin & Schroeder's "*An introduction to Quantum Field Theory*":

in [1], page 251 (Section 7.5), in calculation of the vacuum polarisation diagram in **QED**,

> $$...\:\sim\:\Gamma(2-\frac{d}{2})g^{\mu\nu}...$$
> We would have expected a pole at $d=2$, since the quadratic divergence in $ dimensions becomes a logarithmic divergence in 2 dimensions. But the pole cancels. The Ward identity is working.

also page 525 (Section 16.5) , One-Loop divergences of **Non-Abelian Gauge Theory**--The gauge Boson Self-Energy:

> Now we are ready to put these results together. In the sum of the three diagrams,  The coefficient of $\Gamma(1-\frac{d}{2})g^{\mu\nu}...$ is
>
> $$...=(1-\frac{d}{2})(d-2).$$
> The first factor cancels the pole of the gamma function at $d=2$. Thus, the sum of the three diagrams has no quadratic divergence and no gauge boson mass renormalisation.

in [2]. However, in page 328 (Section 10.2), calculating the self-energy diagram in **$\lambda\phi^4$ theory**, there is the contribution:

> $$\Gamma(1-\frac{d}{2})...$$

which has a pole at $d=2$, and no comment is made there.

**Q2:** I've always thought that in DREG, as long as the $d=4$ divergences are canceled, everything is fine, so what's the significance in talking about $d=2$ divergence?

**Q3:** Is there any serious problem to overlook the $d=2$ pole, for example, in  $\lambda\phi^4$ theory?

**Q4:** By the way, is the "*fine-tunning problem*" related to the $d=2$ pole in DREG, if yes, how?

Comment: I assume the Ward identity mentioned states that there should be no divergences somehow, and if this Ward identity is valid for $d=2$ as well, the cancellation of divergences in $d=2$ is a check on the result. $\lambda\phi^4$ has fewer identities restricting divergences. **Q2**: That's the case when only considering the theory at $d=4$. Sometimes it is useful to consider other dimensionalities to understand better what's going on.

Comment: Quadratic divergences for a scalar are perfectly fine and does not cause problems. Quadratic divergences for gauge bosons on the other hand are a huge problem because renormalisation then introduces a mass counter-term which ruins the gauge symmetry, that's why he mentions the lack of such divergences in the gauge cases.